# Interpolation with mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, interpolation

I have a list of 69 point X= {x1,x2,....x69}. How i can interpolate the points and create a new list X1 from the interpolation of the curve but with 2059 point? 
Can i Interpolate the points, than make a Table for the obtained function?

Comment: Please read about `Interpolation` in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

one way:

```
to = 10;
oldData = {#, RandomReal[]} & /@ Range[to];
f = Interpolation[oldData, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
newData = {#, f[#]} & /@ FindDivisions[{1, to}, 40];

ListPlot[{newData, oldData}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Directive[PointSize[Medium]], Red}, Blue}, 
 Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"new data", "old data"}]
```

gives

[image]

(ps. using V9 with new `PlotLegend` option)